# mpm_prefork:error (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process

Tags: apache-2.4, fedora, ulimit, mpm-prefork

After [having some issues](https://serverfault.com/questions/817593/invalid-argument-ah03139-ap-queue-pop-failed) I have rebuilt my server on a new, clean Fedora 24 platform. It's a fairly busy server, and now when it starts up, I get a flood of these messges in apache's error_log:

```
[Thu Dec 08 19:30:26.954314 2016] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 379] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Thu Dec 08 19:30:36.957269 2016] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 379] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Thu Dec 08 19:30:46.963876 2016] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 379] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Thu Dec 08 19:30:56.967167 2016] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 379] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Thu Dec 08 19:31:06.974127 2016] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 379] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
```

I have tried tweaking and tuning, and nothing seems to resolve the issue. I am using the exact same machine that worked fine under Fedora 23, so I know it can handle the load.

Here is my apache server-status:

```
Apache Server Status for example.com (via x.x.x.x)

Server Version: Apache/2.4.23 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.0.2j-fips PHP/5.6.28
Server MPM: prefork
Server Built: Jul 18 2016 15:38:14
Current Time: Thursday, 08-Dec-2016 19:38:57 UTC
Restart Time: Thursday, 08-Dec-2016 19:29:02 UTC
Parent Server Config. Generation: 1
Parent Server MPM Generation: 0
Server uptime: 9 minutes 55 seconds
Server load: 2.86 2.38 1.48
Total accesses: 13045 - Total Traffic: 112.5 MB
CPU Usage: u485.32 s25.57 cu.05 cs.03 - 85.9% CPU load
21.9 requests/sec - 193.6 kB/second - 8.8 kB/request
165 requests currently being processed, 0 idle workers
KKKKWKKKKKKKKKKKKKKWKKKKKWKKKKKWWKKKKKKKKKKWKKKWKKKWKKKKKKKWWKKW
WKKKKKKKKKKWKKKKKKWKKKWKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKWKKK
KKKKKKKWWKKKKWKKKKKKKKWKKKKKKKKKKKWKW...........................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
```

...and it goes on from there. There are lots of open slots, but *something* on the server is preventing new processes from starting up and handling the load. However my ulimits are set high - probably too high!

```
# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1546671
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 102400
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1546671
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

For completeness, here are my limits.conf settings:

```
*            soft    core            unlimited
*            soft    nofile          102400
*            hard    nofile          152400
*            soft    sigpending      1546671
*            hard    sigpending      2046671
*            soft    stack           10240
*            hard    stack           14240
*            soft    nproc           1546671
*            hard    nproc           2046671
```

And here are my apache mpm-worker settings - again, probably too high, but with all of these set lower (or to the defaults) the problem exists as well, often much faster.

```
ServerLimit       8192
StartServers        40
MinSpareServers     25
MaxSpareServers    100
MaxClients        8192
MaxRequestsPerChild 10000
```

Clearly something is still limiting new processes from starting, but I'm stumped as to where to look next.

Any advice is appreciated, as always!

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Well the first thing I notice now is that the new server is mpm-prefork, the old server was mpm-worker...

Comment: Changing back to mpm-worker did not solve the performance issues.

Answer (score -1):

Tentative solution is to add the following to httpd.conf:

```
EnableMMAP Off
```

This disables memory mapping, which seems to have had a very adverse affect on the server.

For details see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#enablemmap

If this turns out not to be the solution, I will update folks here.

Comment: Well, it seems to have helped, but is not the solution. Now tinkering with Apache mpm-worker tuning and system limits.

Answer (score -1):

We had a similar Problem.
It seams that `systemd` was responsible for our limitation.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#TasksMax=N